# Traffic encryption between ec2 and EKS pods

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We are deploying our app to the EKS, and have a hybrid situation where some services aren't deployed yet within the EKS cluster.

We want the traffic between services deployed on EC2 instances would be encrypted during communication with services deployed in the EKS.

Both apps deployed on EC2 and pods, are java based app deployed on application server.

What is the best practice to do that.. ? In terms of deploying tls certification on the app server, etc...

Comment: Is there any reason the answer wouldn’t be “use HTTPS”?

Comment: what about the tls keys ? shouldn't they be deployed on the app server in order to trust the connection among services ?

Comment: This kind of question is better suited to be asked on Server Fault.